# Outllok adds HTML Table's rows extra white spaces

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm trying to create a email sign. and I thought I did it but in mobile nested tables rows have extra whitespace, how can I remove it?

[image]

What I Wrote:

```
<table class="tg" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="813" height="146" style="display:block; border-collapse: collapse; border:hidden; max-height:156px; max-width:813px">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0072bc" style="display: block; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;" valign="middle" class="">
            <a href="https://www.isverenim.com">
                <img style="margin: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;" src="https://sgkkurumsal.com/Content-Home/img/beBolunmusImzalar/a.png" width="250" height="146">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#0072bc" style="display: block; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;" valign="middle" class="">
            <img style="margin: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;" src="https://sgkkurumsal.com/Content-Home/img/beBolunmusImzalar/b.png" width="154" height="146">
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#0072bc" style="display: block; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;" valign="middle" class="">
            <a href="https://www.bariserdem.com"><img style="margin: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;" src="https://sgkkurumsal.com/Content-Home/img/beBolunmusImzalar/c.png" width="232" height="146">
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#0072bc" style="display: block; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;" valign="middle" class="">
            <img style="margin: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;" src="https://sgkkurumsal.com/Content-Home/img/beBolunmusImzalar/d.png" width="71" height="146">
        </td>
        <td>
            <table style="display:block; border-collapse: collapse; border:hidden;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="106" height="146">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#0072bc" style="display: block; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;" valign="middle" class="" width="106" height="51">
                            <img style="vertical-align: middle; border-spacing: 0; min-height: 54px;" valign="middle" alt="companyname logo" aria-hidden="true" border="0" src="https://sgkkurumsal.com/Content-Home/img/beBolunmusImzalar/e1.png" width="106" height="51">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#0072bc" style="display: block; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;" valign="middle" class="" width="106" height="27">
                            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com"><img style="vertical-align: middle; border-spacing: 0; min-height: 54px;" valign="middle" alt="companyname logo" aria-hidden="true" border="0" src="https://sgkkurumsal.com/Content-Home/img/beBolunmusImzalar/e2.png" width="106" height="27">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#0072bc" style="display: block; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;" valign="middle" class="" width="106" height="27">
                            <a href="https://www.twitter.com"><img style="vertical-align: middle; border-spacing: 0; min-height: 54px;" valign="middle" alt="companyname logo" aria-hidden="true" border="0" src="https://sgkkurumsal.com/Content-Home/img/beBolunmusImzalar/e3.png" width="106" height="27">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#0072bc" style="display: block; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;" valign="middle" class="" width="106" height="41">
                            <img style="vertical-align: middle; border-spacing: 0; min-height: 54px;" valign="middle" alt="companyname logo" aria-hidden="true" border="0" src="https://sgkkurumsal.com/Content-Home/img/beBolunmusImzalar/e4.png" width="106" height="41">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </thead>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: Not sure if it will fix it but you have 3 `</a>` you need to add to your code.

Comment: thanks I just realised that i missed closing a tags but its not the solution for my problem